# Legality of using Business name for copyright notice on website?

Tags: copyright, business

I have read that a copyright notice should include

> 3) the name of the owner of copyright in the work, or an abbreviation
>   by which the name can be recognized, or a generally known alternative
>   designation of the owner.

REFERENCE:https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/19310/website-copyright-should-i-use-my-name-or-the-websites-name

I would like to use my business name in the copyright notice on my website (the business name is the same name as the website name).

Example ----------> On www.business-name.com

Copyright © 2017 Business-name ABN XXXXXXXXX. All Rights Reserved.

Am I right in thinking that the business name is an alternative designation of the owner in this case? Therefore using the business name in the copyright notice is ok?

The business name is registered in Australia.

Comment: You are not your business. Your business is not you. Put the copyright holder's name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A copyright notice is *not* required to protect copyright - all it does is identify the copyright holder which can allow other people to contact them to seek permission to use the copyright material and provide evidence that the person owns the copyright in any action about the copyright.

The person you should identify is the person who owns the copyright. If that is you it should be your name, if it is your company it should be your company's name. A business name is an official 'alias' that could apply to either you or your company depending on how it was registered - you can use that if you like but the correct designation for a business name is "[legal name] trading as [business name]". Typically the legal name is in a much smaller font than the business name.